# How to deploy Nodejs application with Apollo server package in at Opsworks (AWS)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, apollo-server, aws-opsworks

I created one simple nodejs application and added some required packages as below: graphql md5 base-64, etc.

I can deploy this nodejs application in *AWS Opsworks.*

After that, while adding the Apollo server package in nodejs application, I am not able to deploy my Opsworks application. Every time, It is just stuck in running_setup mode. I am not getting any errors.

Is it possible to deploy the *apollo server* application at Opsworks?
If yes, then provide steps for deployment.